Alphabetically order custom post type in elementor query
I need to order some custom post types alphabetically. I've added a value to elementor loop grid to set a custom query that I can intercept inside my functions.php file. I named it custom_charts. As I know I can then modify the output of elementor by using the elementor/query/custom_charts so at the moment I have this code
function custom_chart_sorting($query){
  $query->set('post_type', 'tracks');
  $query->set('meta_key', 'track_position'); //This is a custom field I've added with ACF to do the sorting but maybe there is a best way
  $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
  $query->set('order', 'ASC');
}
add_action('elementor/query/custom_charts', 'custom_chart_sorting');

The query at the moment works fine, but how I can avoid to repeat the $query->set() and is there a better way to alpabetically order my cpt when the query is executed and posts retrived?
